How to read from event grid namespace using http get request
I am currently wokrung on azure event grid namespace. Here I am receiving certain data in IotHub. From IotHub I routed the message using message routing to Event Grid Namespace. Now using dart language http.get() I am trying to print the response body. But I am getting error

Error fetching data: XMLHttpRequest error.

Previously in other azure services I encountered this error using CORS I'm able to overcome this error. But Unfortunately, in Azure Event Grid Namespace there is no CORS feature. Is there any other way to read from event grid from flutter (dart).
Below is my code
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> fetchDataFromEventGrid() async {
  final url = 'https://<namespace name>.<region>.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events';
  final apiKey = 'API key';  // If your endpoint requires an API key

  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'aeg-sas-key': apiKey,  // Azure Event Grid requires the aeg-sas-key header for authentication
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      print('Data received from Event Grid: $data');
    } else {
      print('Failed to load data. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching data: $e');
  }
}

void main() async {
  await fetchDataFromEventGrid();
}

ran the commands. gets following warning and error


disable and re-enable CORS checks for Flutter's

Installation dart pub global activate flutter_cors Usage fluttercors --disable

looks like fluttercors --disable is not recognised .  other way add the  port like this  and run the application  again.

what I should give system IPV4 or same 127.0.0.0?

is your application loading under 55610

Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64098/XZQmXhDN-yk=/ws

64098 is changing every time application is run

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

dart pub global activate flutter_cors

The above script is used to disable and re-enable CORS checks for Flutter's Chrome instances.
Note:
This script only disables CORS checks for local testing and will not resolve CORS issues in production. Please refrain from seeking help for production CORS issues as they fall outside the scope of this project.
If you encounter CORS issues during local development, utilize flutter_cors to disable CORS checks in the Chrome instance used by Flutter for web development. Additionally, ensure to adjust the Address range in Networking according to the loaded end range.

The code below is designed to make a request to fetch data from the Azure Event Grid:

'dart:convert';

Future<void> fetchDataFromEventGrid() async {   final url =
'https://<namespace name>.<region>.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events';  
final apiKey = 'API key';  // Replace with your actual API key

  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'aeg-sas-key': apiKey,  // Azure Event Grid requires the aeg-sas-key header for authentication
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      print('Data received from Event Grid: $data');
    } else {
      print('Failed to load data. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }   } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching data: $e');   } }

void main() async {   await fetchDataFromEventGrid(); } 




changed the IPV4 address range as you mentioned still getting same error.

Can you share the error in text format, which is displaying in the UI and console?
